# Parse Error currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

For some reason I'm getting an error in my app with this line:

```
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
```

It's been working perfectly before but as soon as I deleted the "TestObject" class from Parse my app started crashing at this line.

I'd like to add that it works fine in the simulator but it crashes when I run on my device with a "EXC_BAD_ACCSS" error.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to update your question with details about the crash including the complete and exact error.

Answer (score -1):

You should follow the instructions in parse.com docs push notifications for setting deviceToken

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide